# "Insert into select from group by count on duplicate update" combo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this main MySQL table `analytika` :

```
ID  |  aa_current  |  aa_referrer  | aa_mobile | ......

1      index.html     ----           false       ......
2      frank.html     ----           false       ......
3      lenon.html     ----           true        ......
4      index.html     ----           false       ......
5      lemon.html     ----           false       ......
```

What I'm trying to do is have a php code executed by cron every night, that will take the data from this large `analytika` table, group them by frequencies and insert them into the separate table just for every column. (so I have other tables for the columns like `analytika_pages` where just the aa_current data should go etc.)

This is one of the subtable's desired outcome `analytika_pages`:

```
ID  |  aa_current  |  count

1      index.html     2
2      frank.html     1
3      lenon.html     1
5      lemon.html     1
```

The main struggle I have is combining all the actions into the query. Im very beginner so I put this up from multiple sources, Im almost there, but what does it missing is taking the COUNT and inserting it alongside the aa_current.

```
INSERT INTO analytika_pages(aa_current)
    SELECT aa_current
    FROM
    (SELECT aa_current, COUNT(aa_current) AS pocet FROM analytika GROUP BY aa_current ORDER BY pocet DESC) as sb
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + pocet
```

And to repeat what I need:

- take all the data from the main table
- focus on one specific column
- group its rows by frequencies
- inserting them into separate table made just for this value
- the separate table also needs the number of occurrences (the COUNT from the query) filled in
- needs to work as an insert or if exists, update.

Comment: which is the key column for your table ??

Comment: @scaisEdge ID is the primary key in the target table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also retrive a valid id  ..  for let the DUPLICATE  KEY condition work too

```
INSERT INTO analytika_pages(id, aa_current, count)
select min(id), aa_current, count(aa_current)
FROM analytika 
GROUP BY aa_current
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + pocet
```

*(but are you sure the id between the two table are alway coherent  ??)*